# replace a number in a the row of a matrix if certain condition is met in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

How to replace a number in a row of a matrix if certain condition is met? For example, how i replace the numbers in the last row equal to zero if they are less than 3?

```
A:
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
[ 2,  4, 10,  1]])
```

It should look like:

```
A:
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
[ 0,  4, 10,  0]])
```

Comment: Replace them with what? All the same number? Values from a list?

Comment: Replace with zero. If any number in the last column is less than 3 replace it with zero

Comment: @AlbertoAlvarez, did one of the below solutions help? if so, feel free to accept one (tick on left).

Answer (score 1):

This transformation can be performed in-place directly:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
               [ 2,  4, 10,  1]])

A[-1][A[-1] < 3] = 0

# matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [ 0,  4, 10,  0]])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply that logic to all elements, you might want to go with something like this:

```
In [21]: a=[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
    ...:    [ 2,  4, 10,  1]]
    ...:    
    ...: 

In [22]: b = list()

In [23]: l = lambda v: 0 if v < 3 else v

In [24]: for r in a:
    ...:     b.append(list(map(l, r)))
    ...:     

In [25]: b
Out[25]: [[0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 4, 10, 0]]
```